# How to handle in Reactor Netty an io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I'm trying to use Reactor Netty TcpClient in reactive way to interact with hosts, that may be unreachable. Here is an example of a channel initialization logic:

```java
ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = ConnectionProvider.fixed("fixed", 50);
TcpClient.create(connectionProvider)
  .host(host).port(port)
  .wiretap(true)
  .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 50)
  .doOnConnect(x -> log.trace("Connect to {}:{}", host, port))
  .doOnConnected(conn -> log.trace("Connected {}", conn.channel()))
  .connect()
  .subscribe(this::utilizeConnection);
```

the output, that i receiving :

```
2019-09-04 08:23:13.612 TRACE 71988 --- [ioEventLoop-4-3] c.c.pcb.poc.network.tcp.NettyTcpSender   : Connect to 192.168.88.210:2000
2019-09-04 08:23:13.684  WARN 71988 --- [actor-tcp-nio-4] io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise  : An exception was thrown by reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.operationComplete()

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.88.210:2000
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.88.210:2000
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:267) ~[netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127) ~[netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:405) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) [netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:906) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:4.1.36.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.create(Mono.java:183)
    reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.acquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:130)
Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
    |_  Mono.create ⇢ reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider.acquire(PooledConnectionProvider.java:130)
    |_  Mono.doOnSubscribe ⇢ reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientDoOn.connect(TcpClientDoOn.java:58)
```

The 'inbound' and 'outbound' are having a dedicated method to handle their errors, but they works on top of a Connection instance that won't be created if you got the 'connection timeout'.

I tried:

1. The exception, that i receiving is wrapped in 'ErrorCallbackNotImplemented'. But I wasn't able to find any way to implement any 'ErrorCallback'
2. The log contains a warning message from 'io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise' . but I wasn't able to find a way how to make own Promise to handle it in a right way.
3. No any configurations i've found that may somehow intercept connection timeouts.
4. *workaround*. The blocked approach to create a connection ( .block() instead of .subscribe()) will allow me to catch any Connection creating exceptions within plain try-catch block, but i'll lose the benefits of reactive approach with such workaround.

Do somebody may suggest me at least something to help me to find a right way to handle a 'io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not forget to implement your *error callback*

Usually `reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` happens when there is subscription over labmda based `.subscribe` method (same for `Mono` and `Flux`).

If you are going to look at the sources [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/LambdaSubscriber.java#L148) and [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/LambdaMonoSubscriber.java#L151), you will find the place where `reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented` is thrown!

## Action Points

In order to handle the original `io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException`  I would recommend looking at [Handling Errors](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#which.errors) section of the original Project Reactor documentation